# OpenGL multiple VBO

Tags: opengl

If I have two different primitive types which are drawn dynamically according to user input, should I use 2 separate VBOs or is there a way of using one and of somehow identifying where the different primitive vertices begin and end?

The primitive types are triangle strips and points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either method works. If using a VBO the `data` parameter of the `gl…Pointer` functions is interpreted as a numeric byte offset into the VBO. It's perfectly possible to put seveal batches of vertex attributes into a single VBO and point OpenGL to the sections within the VBO by their offsets.

So before each `glDraw…` call use the right `gl…Pointer` calls to set the right offsets. Or even better yet (if supported, i.e. you've got a new enough OpenGL version): Use *Vertex Array Objects* to encapsulate whole set of `gl…Pointer` settings into one abstract object that can be bound by a single OpenGL call.